# Is spin() event driven?

Tags: ros, spin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am wondering how efficient ros::spin() is. Is it event driven so that when messages come in callbacks get called immediately? Or is it simply polling behind the scenes, and if so, how fast?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321509/is-spin()-event-driven?/) by [Peter Gissel](https://answers.ros.org/users/40960/peter-gissel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the [Callbacks and Subscribers wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning#Single-threaded_Spinning),

```
#include <ros/callback_queue.h>
ros::NodeHandle n;
while (ros::ok())
{
  ros::getGlobalCallbackQueue()->callAvailable(ros::WallDuration(0.1));
}
```

Is the equivalent implementation of `ros::spin()`.

Edit: From @gvdhoorn's comments below, `callAvaliable` [waits on a condition variable](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/89ca9a7bf288b09d033a1ab6966ef8cfe39e1002/clients/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp#L304-L357) for the given duration, making spin majority event driven.

---

Originally posted by [BryceWilley](https://answers.ros.org/users/33606/brycewilley/) with karma: 711 on 2019-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Peter Gissel](https://answers.ros.org/users/40960/peter-gissel/) on 2019-04-21**:
Thanks for the answer, I saw that code also. It doesn't actually answer my question, however. What is callAvailable() doing? Is it polling or event driven?

**Comment by [BryceWilley](https://answers.ros.org/users/33606/brycewilley/) on 2019-04-22**:
It think it does answer your question though: it's continuous looping (i.e. polling) the global callback queue, only calling subscribers if something is available. If `spin()` was event driven it would sleep forever and wait for other threads to spawn or a OS level signal to be handled in another callback.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-22**:
`callAvailable(..)` (and `callOne(..)`) use a timed-wait on a condition variable ([here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/89ca9a7bf288b09d033a1ab6966ef8cfe39e1002/clients/roscpp/src/libros/callback_queue.cpp#L304-L357)). The time-out is used to put an upper-bound on the tightness of the loop.

@Peter Gissel: I'd say it's not *really* polling, but it's also not completely event based (`spin(..)` that is, waiting on a condition variable is event-based).

**Comment by [BryceWilley](https://answers.ros.org/users/33606/brycewilley/) on 2019-04-22**:
@gvdhoorn is right here, you could easily make the above loop event-based by increasing the timeout then, ignore my previous comment.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-22**:
Well it is event-based. It's just that the time-out is there to avoid hanging forever in `callAvailable(..)`, which would be annoying/undesirable if `ros::ok()` becomes `false` while you're waiting (as anything using ROS client infrastructure would then fail).